# Grepl function not working in R

Tags: r, filter, grepl

I am trying to grep for multiple strings in the data frame

```
head(data1) 

colname.x 

Facebook
POF Free Dating App
WhatsApp Messenger
WhatsApp Messenger
Facebook
Facebook
Facebook
Facebook
WhatsApp Messenger
POF Free Dating App
Facebook
Facebook
WhatsApp Messenger
Facebook
Messenger
Facebook
Facebook
Dropbox
WhatsApp Messenger
Facebook
Dropbox
WhatsApp Messenger
WhatsApp Messenger
Facebook
```

I am appending the data frame to include new social media column

```
data1$socialmedia <- as.numeric(grepl("messenger | facebook | whatsapp " , data1$colname.x ))
```

However all I get is 0 i.e FALSE instead of True/1 where Facebook/Whatsapp etc is present, I am not sure why this is the case.

Comment: the words in your data start with a capital letter, ulike your pattern. Maybe, try `tolower(data1$colname.x)`

Comment: ...and you have spaces in your pattern - do you have them in your data? Impossible for us to tell!

Comment: You have spaces in between the words and the vertical bars, which is the most likely problem. (The spaces are matched literally).  If you're new to regular expressions, test out your expressions here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: you might want to add `ignore.case=TRUE` to  your `grepl` to ignore upper and lower case differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is space, uppercase, encoding sensitive!

try

`data1$socialmedia <- as.numeric(grepl("Messenger|Facebook|WhatsApp",data1$colname.x ))`

if you explain your idea better I can provide a better answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer  , i would certainly try and provide better formatted and worded questions next time .